# Variants of startup scripts

Tags: gentoo, init-script, sysvinit, systemctl

i have read of multiple options to have a script executed on startup on my gentoo linux:

- systemd-service
- init.d
- local.d
- cron

are there any other options beside these?

Comment: Could you possibly fill out your question with an actual issue that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

To add to your list, it depends on what level you would like this script to be executed. For example, you can add it to your shell init script (e.g. `.bashrc`), which would make it run every time a new shell is started by default (potentially risky). If you are loading up X on this machine, you can also hook it to the startup of the X11 server (e.g. `.xinitrc`). Yet another option is for executing it at the start of the desktop environment if the setup consists of one that supports that type of feature (e.g. modifying the appropriate `dotfile` for that environment).

Long story short, it depends on the use-case. At a more system-wide implementation, the `systemd` and `rc` systems are your best bet.